# Vue-CLI importing global scss file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to populate an `scss` file for the `Vue-cli` project in **App.vue** which has been

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i|Rubik:300,400,500,700,700i,900');
  @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
  @import "./assets/css/style";
</style>
```

From node modules bootstrap `SCSS` work properly, but it's not working when I kept `style.scss`on assets folder !

Comment: any reason why you're importing the SCSS through `<style>` and not in `<script>`

Comment: So how can import scss file through a script ?and where I kept the script.....

Answer (score 0):

Import from your `main.js` file, like this:

```
import '@/assets/css/style';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to need to create a `vue.config.js` file on `Vue CLI 3+` main directory, which has to contain the following code snippet

```
module.exports = {
   css: {
    loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
            data: `
      @import "@/assets/css/style.scss";
    `
        }
     }
   }
};
```

Comment: you rapidly deleted your question but I updated the duplicate link and you can do what you want

Comment: Yeah! When you mark duplicate I am getting a little bit nervous and disappointed but I get solutions!

Comment: I am not the one who initially marked the question as duplicate and the first duplicate was bad ... I edited with another one more accurate

Comment: Once I was banned for a long time, and I could not get write answer/questions or anything so that I try to remove duplicate or similar questions

Comment: So it was bad practice or what should I do?

Comment: read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/8620333 you will find a whole section dealing with deleted posts and nothing about duplicate --> *Do not delete your posts. As explained above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do still count toward the question ban. Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only fixing does!*

Comment: Okay! I will check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197485/discussion-between-momin-and-temani-afif).